# Наследуют ли псевдоклассы правила своих селекторов?

Tags: css

Для ссылок задано:

```
a { text-decoration: none; }
```

Наследуется ли это правило псевдоклассами селектора (`a:hover`, `a:focus`, `a:active` и пр.)?

Comment: Разве в браузере если открыть `F12` там не показан ответ на ваш вопрос ?

Answer (score 1):

Селекторы: **a**, **a:hover**, **a:active** и т.п. задают правила на теги **a**.

Следовательно задав свойство тегу **a**

```
a { text-decoration: none; }
```

и не переопределив его в других селекторах, то оно будет работать и с псевдоселекторами. Это никак не связано с наследованием.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри на пример и сам ответь на свой вопрос наследуют ли ???
Только в данном примере не проверить active, так как он в фокус срабатывает сразу

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #272727;
  perspective: 100px;
  color: white;
}

a {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  border: 5px solid red;
  margin: auto;
  color: black;
  background: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: red;
  background: green;
}

a:active {
  color: red;
  background: yellow;
}

a:focus {
  color: black;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" target="_blank">я ссылка</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

В чистом css наследуют. Но если подключен внешний css (например bootstrap), то это уже от него зависит.